# Color row in spreadsheet (google script)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

What am I doing wrong?

I want to:
Color the row green when a field in column 16 contains data
Color the row white when a field in column 16 contains no data

With this piece of code the row becomes green when I enter data in column 16, but when I delete the data in column 16 it does not turn white. It is onEdit.

```
if (r.getColumn() == 16 && status.length == 0) {
    rowRange.setBackground("#00FF58");
} else if (r.getColumn() == 16 && status.length != 0) {
    rowRange.setBackground("#FFFFFF");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Conditional Formatting (ie what is "wrong" *might* be the approach!):

[image: SO22131208 examle]

You may care to adjust the range but if extended far it will give rise to delay in updating.